# Proper way to print objects from ArrayList within Criteria

Tags: java

I am going to try my best to explain what I'm trying to do. First, here are my classes:

**HouseListTester Class**

```
    package RealEstateListings;
import java.util.*;

public class HouseListTester {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create scanner for user input via console
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        
        System.out.println("Welcome to Mike's House Listing");
        System.out.println("Please enter the file name of the house list: ");
        String sourceFolder = "C:\\Users\\micha\\Documents\\eclipse-workspace\\Real Estate Listings\\src\\RealEstateListings\\";
        HouseList fileName = new HouseList(sourceFolder+input.next());
        
        System.out.println();
        
        System.out.println("Please enter your search criteria");
        
        System.out.print("Minimum price: ");
        int minPrice = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Maximum price: ");
        int maxPrice = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Minimum area: ");
        int minArea = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Maximum area: ");
        int maxArea = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Minimum number of bedrooms: ");
        int minBedrooms = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Maximum number of bedrooms: ");
        int maxBedrooms = input.nextInt();
        
        Criteria userCriteria = new Criteria(minPrice, maxPrice, minArea, maxArea, minBedrooms, maxBedrooms);
        
        fileName.printHouses(userCriteria); 
    }
}
```

**HouseList Class**

```
    package RealEstateListings;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    public class HouseList {
    
        public ArrayList<House>houseList;
        
        
        public HouseList(String fileName) {
            houseList = new ArrayList<House>();
            try {
                //create scanner to read input
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
            
                while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    //input reads to parameters    address     price         area          numBedrooms
                    House newListing = new House(sc.next(), sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt());
                    //add newListing to houseList array
                    houseList.add(newListing);
                }
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println("File was not found.");
            }
            System.out.println(houseList.size()+" houses created.");
            }
            
        public void printHouses(Criteria c) {
            
            for(int i = 0; i<houseList.size();i++) 
                if(houseList.get(i).satisfies(c))
                    System.out.println(houseList.get(i).toString());
                
            }
        
        public String getHouse(Criteria C) {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

**House Class**

```
    package RealEstateListings;
    
    public class House {
        String address;
        int price,area,numberOfBedrooms;
        
        public House(String addr, int salePrice, int saleArea, int numBedrooms) {
            this.address = addr;
            this.price = salePrice;
            this.area = saleArea;
            this.numberOfBedrooms = numBedrooms;
        }
        
        public String getAddress() {return this.address;}
        public int getPrice() {return this.price;}
        public int getArea() {return this.area;}
        public int getNumberOfBedrooms() {return this.numberOfBedrooms;}
        
        public boolean satisfies(Criteria c) {
            
            if(c.getMinimumPrice() <= this.getPrice() && c.getMaximumPrice() >= this.getPrice())
                if(c.getMaximumArea() <= this.getArea() && c.getMaximumArea() >= this.getArea()) 
                    if(c.getMinNumBedrooms() <= this.getNumberOfBedrooms() && c.getMaxNumBedrooms() >= this.getNumberOfBedrooms())
                        return true;
            
            return false;
            
        }
        
        public String toString() {return this.getAddress();}
    }
```

**Criteria Class**

```
    package RealEstateListings;
    
    public class Criteria {
        
        int minimumPrice, maximumPrice, minimumArea, maximumArea; 
        int minimumNumberOfBedrooms, maximumNumberOfBedrooms;
        
        public Criteria(int minPrice, int maxPrice, int minArea, int maxArea, int minBedrooms, int maxBedrooms) {
            
            this.minimumPrice = minPrice;
            this.maximumPrice = maxPrice;
            this.minimumArea = minArea;
            this.maximumArea = maxArea;
            this.minimumNumberOfBedrooms = minBedrooms;
            this.maximumNumberOfBedrooms = maxBedrooms;
            
        }
        
        public int getMinimumPrice() {return minimumPrice;}
        public int getMaximumPrice() {return maximumPrice;}
        public int getMinimumArea() {return minimumArea;}
        public int getMaximumArea() {return maximumArea;}
        public int getMinNumBedrooms() {return minimumNumberOfBedrooms;}
        public int getMaxNumBedrooms() {return maximumNumberOfBedrooms;}
    }
```

My current console output, after running:

```
Welcome to Mike's House Listing
Please enter the file name of the house list: 
houses.txt
25 houses created.

Please enter your search criteria
Minimum price: 1
Maximum price: 1000000
Minimum area: 1
Maximum area: 1000000
Minimum number of bedrooms: 1
Maximum number of bedrooms: 1000
```

The houses.txt file includes a string, and three integers on every line, I've tested that the ArrayList is being created correctly, so my problem doesn't stem from there.

**Question/Where I am confused:**
I am attempting to use the **printHouses** function located in the **HouseList Class**. I am looking to print out all the houses which satisfy the criteria, from which the user has entered in the main method located in the **HouseListTester Class**. However, upon the user entering the criteria, no houses are listed. I am unsure as to what is causing this happen, I suspect it is something to do with me improperly calling to the **toString function** in the **House Class**. Or perhaps I am improperly calling to the printHouses function from the main method. I called to the printHouses function, using an object (fileName) which was first used to create an ArrayList of houses, and later, reused the same object to call to the printHouses function.

My concern is that no houses are printed at all, I believe my satisfied (located in Criteria Class) is working properly, and I also know the userCriteria object (located in HouseListTester) is created correctly from me testing other functions from that class on the newly created object.

**Why aren't the houses which satisfy my said criteria being printed?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in your `satisfies` method in your `House` class, instead of this

```
public boolean satisfies(Criteria c) {
            
            if(c.getMinimumPrice() <= this.getPrice() && c.getMaximumPrice() >= this.getPrice())
                if(c.getMaximumArea() <= this.getArea() && c.getMaximumArea() >= this.getArea()) 
                    if(c.getMinNumBedrooms() <= this.getNumberOfBedrooms() && c.getMaxNumBedrooms() >= this.getNumberOfBedrooms())
                        return true;
            
            return false;
            
        }
```

You'll need this

```
public boolean satisfies(Criteria c) {
            
            if(c.getMinimumPrice() <= this.getPrice() && c.getMaximumPrice() >= this.getPrice())
                if(c.getMinimumArea() <= this.getArea() && c.getMaximumArea() >= this.getArea()) 
                    if(c.getMinNumBedrooms() <= this.getNumberOfBedrooms() && c.getMaxNumBedrooms() >= this.getNumberOfBedrooms())
                        return true;
            
            return false;
            
        }
```

Notice this line

if(<s>c.getMaximumArea()</s> <= this.getArea() && c.getMaximumArea() >= this.getArea())

Should be

if(**c.getMinimumArea()** <= this.getArea() && c.getMaximumArea() >= this.getArea())